# Issue with generate_series in case sentence

Tags: postgresql, case, generate-series

Recently my team have updated the version of our postgres server from 9.3 to 10.1

One of our procedures has a piece of code that right now is giving us some problems. This is just an example base on the original code:

```
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN current_date = '2017-12-14'    THEN generate_series(current_date , '2017-12-31'::DATE , '1 day') 
                WHEN current_date = '2017-12-15'    THEN generate_series(current_date , '2017-12-31'::DATE , '1 day') 
                ELSE generate_series('2017-12-01'::DATE, '2017-12-31'::DATE, '1 day') 
             END AS workday
```

If I run this code in our previous server I've got the sequence. However in postgres 10.1 I'am getting this error message:

"set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE. "

Is there any problem with this version of postgres is this a bug, or is there another way to get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the set-returning functions out of the CASE statement so that it only returns a single row at a time. I would simplify your statement by making the CASE a subquery that you use the resulting column from:

```
SELECT generate_series(series_start_date::DATE, '2017-12-31'::DATE, '1 day') FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN current_date='2017-12-14' THEN current_date
                WHEN current_date='2017-12-15' THEN current_date
                ELSE '2017-12-01'
            END AS series_start_date
    ) as temp_alias;
```

That query should give you what you want.

Putting 'temp_alias' in there is required, but isn't used.

Disclaimer: I tested this on Postgres 9.6, which is all I have available to test with at the moment. It should work with Postgres 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

The use of set-returning functions in scalar contexts was a hack. They were completely rewritten by Andres Freund to a much better implementation.

Release note: [Change the implementation of set-returning functions appearing in a query's SELECT list (Andres Freund)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-10.html).

As an altenative you can use `LATERAL JOIN` to join the logic of determining reference date to `generate_series`:

```
SELECT workday_series.*
FROM
  (SELECT CASE CURRENT_DATE
              WHEN '2017-12-14' THEN CURRENT_DATE
              WHEN '2017-12-15' THEN CURRENT_DATE
              ELSE '2017-12-01'
          END) AS REF (date_reference)
JOIN LATERAL generate_series(ref.date_reference, '2017-12-31'::DATE, '1 day') AS workday_series(workday) ON TRUE;
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/7229).